# Como mapear um enumerador usando EntityTypeConfiguration do Entity Framework 6?

Tags: entity-framework

Boa noite, tenho minha seguinte classe

```
public class Endereco {
    public string Bairro { get; set; }
    public string Cidade { get; set; }
    public EUF Estado { get; set; }
}
```

e meu enumerador

```
public enum EUF {
    SP = 1,
    PR = 2,
    SC = 3
}
```

e minha classe de mapeamento

```
public EnderecoConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Endereco> {
    public EnderecoConfig() {
        Property(x => x.Cidade);
    }
}
```

Como mapeio esse Enum usando EntityTypeConfiguration?

Sou acostumado com o `FLUENT NHIBERNATE` aonde usamos `CustomType<EUF>()`

Comment: Precisa necessariamente utilizar `EntityTypeConfiguration`? Porque não precisa. Dá pra fazer mais simples.

Comment: Sou acostumado em usar Fluent API com nhibernate, acho mais organizado nosso mapeamento, além de não "sujar" as classes com inúmeros annotations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, depois de algumas buscas e tudo mais, tenho a seguinte resposta:

Nada, não precisa fazer nenhuma configuração.

Basta usar `Property(x => x.Estado);`